# Sample of how to create and save new entity, Breezejs

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze

Im trying to create a very basic Todo-entity from the Breeze example.. Im doing:

```
manager.createEntity("Todo",{Description:"Test",Id:32,IsDone:false});
```

But I keep getting an error where the console tells me that it couldnt find the Type "Todo".. I have tried all types I can possibly think of..
Could anyone please provide me with an example of how to create an entity for the breeze WebApiSample.. cause this is driving me nuts..

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Breeze needs metadata in order to create an entity of any type.  That metadata can either be returned from the server or created locally.  My guess is that you haven't yet done either of these.  Metadata from the server is usually automatically fetched by Breeze during its first query against the server. Alternatively you can cause it to be fetched directly via the MetadataStore.fetchMetadata method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok thanks! Right now Im doing the following in the getTodos-function:

manager.metadataStore.fetchMetadata("api/BreezeSample");
        manager.createEntity("BreezeSampleTodoItem", { Description: "Test", IsDone: false, Id: 34 })

Is this correct?.. how do I know what the type-name is supposed to be?.. as for my code above I checked in the Metadata and found that type-name.. but Im not sure if its the correct one..

Comment: You can always look into the metadataStore to see what types are there ( and their names) via yourEntityManager.metadataStore.getEntityTypes().